# Video game not responding correctly to input

Tags: pygame, keyboard-events

I'm developing a pygame video game, and everything was working out perfectly until yesterday. The issues began after I formatted my pc. So when i run the game, the first screen to show up is the 'Menu'. So in this state class I have an event method where when you press the 'p' key it gets you to the 'Play' state. So now it is not working, I don't know why.

I've changed nothing. I just formatted my pc and reinstalled python, pygame and pgu module. But the strange thing comes when I reprogram the videogame so that the first state to show up when you run the game is the 'Play' state, everything works perfectly. It also has an event method where when you press the arrows, the character moves, and when the player presses ESC it takes you to the 'Menu' state.

So again when I'm at the 'Menu' state the game doesn't respond to the input I'm giving to it. I don't really know what's happening.

Comment: Right, so it's confirmed. The game only responds to input if it's in a state where I can control the character. Otherwise, it doesn't work. The key that i press doesn't matter, no key works

Comment: A way that I used is to build multiple while loops and in each of them you add a ```for event in pygame.event.get()``` loop with each time every key that you want to listen. I can make you an eg. tomorow if you want.

Comment: Yes, please. Thanks

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I was saying in comments :

Sorry if all comments are not appropriate to your level but I wanted to be sure you understand it all.

```py
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))


class Menu:
    pass


class Play:
    pass


def main():
    running = True  # here we define the main variable of the main loop
    main_menu = True  # when the main loop will begin, main_menu will begin too
    game = False  # game is false because player didn't press p
    options = False  # options is false because player didn't go to options

    while running:  # begin the main loop

        while main_menu:

            for event in pygame.event.get():  # listen for events

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # if the player quit, ends up the 'main_menu' loop and 'running' loop too
                    running = False
                    main_menu = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_p:  # if p key is pressed, exit from main menu and begin 'game' loop
                        main_menu = False
                        game = True

                    if event.key == pygame.K_o:  # if o key is pressed, exit from main menu and begin 'options' loop
                        main_menu = False
                        options = True

                screen.fill((255, 0, 0))  # I fill the screen in red to make the example more explicit

                pygame.display.flip()  # I update the screen every frame

        while game:

            for event in pygame.event.get():  # listen for events

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # if the player quit, ends up 'running' and 'options' loop
                    running = False
                    game = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  # listen for keys

                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:  # if the player press backspace (delete), ends up 'game' loop
                        game = False                     # and begin (again) the 'main_menu' loop
                        main_menu = True

            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))   # I fill the screen in white to make the example more explicit

            pygame.display.flip()  # I update the screen every frame

        while options:  # same logic for this one

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    options = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        options = False
                        main_menu = True

            screen.fill((0, 255, 0))

            pygame.display.flip()


pygame.init()  # initialize pygame
main()  # begin main loop
pygame.quit()  # quit pygame
```